llvm-cov ignore file regex does not work on windows
I have a large c++ Project which contains serveral shared objects using cmake. I am using gtest and gmock for unit tests and in addition I am using a code coverage extension from here https://github.com/StableCoder/cmake-scripts.git. The code coverage module works with gcc and clang. In addition I modified the script to be able to create code coverage on windows using cmakes -T clang-cl option (clang 17). This works quite well.
Now I have a issue with "ignore-filename-regex" option. While this works on Linux it seems to be ignored on windows. The script from the cmake lib checks the llvm-cov to determine if this option is availble.
e.g. I have the following path shown in browser

code\engine\source\test\system\foo.cpp
my regex is .*[\/\\]test[\/\\].*
I tested the regex using an regex editor to be sure the regex workd
file name option is available (it must be a minimum version of llvm-vov 7)
on Linux it works as expected, on windows not

Does have anyone an idea?

.[/\]test[/\]. is an invalid regex.

sorry, copy'n'paste issue. adjust regexp in post.

[Edit] the question and use proper formatting tools that you see on the editor toolbar. Also find there the help button and see how to format a code.

@MarkaRagnos0815: Note, that visual representation of your regex in the post differs from the one you actually write. It is better to format regex as a code, so its visual representation will be the same as you write it.

I found the issue:
After a little search in the cmake generated project files I found out that the code_covergage.cmake uses ' to stringify the regex, this seems not to work on windows. Changing to " works
not working
-ignore-filename-regex='.*[/\]test[/\].*'

working
-ignore-filename-regex=".*[/\]test[/\].*"

works on both linux/windows
